# Can anyone help me to express this condition in Gams?

Tags: gams-math

I have this condition and want to express it in Gams! But Really dont Know How to do it!

```
  If (t'+L(d)*(1-alfa)=t) ---> Y=1
  Otherwise               ---> Y=0
```

`Y` is a Binary variable, `alfa` is a continuous variable
`L(d)` is a parameter, `t` and `t'` are time sets.

Thanks for your help!